# React/Redux How to filter two array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-redux

I am using react-reselect to filter out some data.
I have to different arrays of data which I have to check if they are matching or not. How can I do a filter with two different arrays and have to run map function on them

Here is my selector

```js
export const AssignedUserSelector = createSelector(
  [EmployeeSelector],
  employee => {
    const freshData = newData.map(newlyAssign => newlyAssign);
   
    return employee.employees.filter(assign => assign.employeeId === newData);
  }
);
```

here freshdata is something like this ["2222","333", "4444"] and employee.employees is like this [{id:"222", name: "John"}, {id:"333", name: "Jane"}, {id:"5555", name: "Josh"}].

What I am trying to do is filter out employees as per the id received. How I can I achieve this in react.

Comment: Why are you mapping via the identity function? It does nothing.

Comment: Just for the sake of the question. I tried doing map inside the filter still doesnot work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you're doing with your example code, but this is probably what you're looking for:

Multiple Ids

```
const employeeIds = ["2222", "333", "4444"];

const employee = {
  employees: [{ 
    id: "222", 
    name: "John"
  },{
    id: "333", 
    name: "Jane"
  },{
    id: "5555", 
    name: "Josh"
  }]
};

employee.employees.filter(({ id }) => !employeeIds.includes(id));
```

Single Id

```
const employeeId = "222";

const employee = {
  employees: [{ 
    id: "222", 
    name: "John"
  },{
    id: "333", 
    name: "Jane"
  },{
    id: "5555", 
    name: "Josh"
  }]
};

employee.employees.filter(({ id }) => id !== employeeId);
```

Comment: Hi thankx for response, my question is I have two arrays and I want to map then filter out array1 id’s matching array2 id’s

Comment: I'm confused. Why do you need to map? Your current map does nothing but return the same collection as a new array.

If your first array `freshData` is simply a collection of one or more ids `['111', '222']` and you want to compare that collection to the employees collection then you don't need to map `freshData` since you're trying to filter the employees collection based on `freshData`. 

Array.map and Array.filter will always return a new array (refs change) so all you'd need to do is filter the employees collection against the ids and return the new filtered array.

Comment: Given the examples above, what is your expected output from the code snippet I posted?